# Find bounded function satisfying f(0)=0, f'(0)=0, and bounded first and second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I am looking for a bounded funtion $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ satisfying $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$ and with bounded first and second derivatives. My intitial idea has been to consider trigonometric functions or compositions of them, but I still haven't found an adequate one. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Trig is a good place to start. How about $\sin^2{x}$?

Comment: thanks man, $sin^2(x)$ seems to do the trick

Comment: Perhaps more obviously: $\cos(x) - 1$

Comment: @Nemo and what would $f'(0)$ be, then?

Comment: sorry,i didn't see it,just though about f(0)=0

Answer (score 1):

f=0.

Now it turns out a reply must be at least thirty characters. Hmm. Humdee hum...

Comment: I forgot to mention different from the null function!

Comment: rats...${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\sin^2 (x)$$

$$f(0)=0$$

$$f'(x)=\cos(x)2\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$$

$$f'(0)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

A good candidate is 
$$
f(x) = \cos(x) - 1
$$